# How can I fix the Julia Pkg error for invalid version string for tar file?

Tags: julia, tar, crc

I have been using Julia for a while now. Suddenly today when I wanted to update a package I get the following error:

[image: Julia Pkg tar error]

This happens for every package, whether it is Pkg.add() or Pkg.update(). Everything worked fine before today. I already tried removing all Julia versions and reinstalling the latest one.

Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself already. When uninstalling Julia, also remove the .julia folder in your user directory (e.g. C:/users/my_name/.julia), before reinstalling.

Comment: So what *has* been the issue?

Comment: I would not know specifically. But I am guessing somethin was wrong in the Pkg package, or something on my systems was wrong, e.g. accessibility issues or corrupt files.